# I want to convert uppercase word to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase but I have a problem

Tags: javascript

```js
let friends = [
  "oMaR",
  "mOhaMed",
  "tAwFIk",
  "aBdO",
  "OmrAn",
  "MoHanD",
  "AbdOlLaH",
];

let result = friends.map((a) => { return a === a.toLowerCase() ? a.toUpperCase() : a.toLowerCase(); }).join(" ");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: so, you want to work with letters, not words?

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that just dumping some code and saying "I have problem" isn't enough for anybody to provide an answer.

Comment: We're not sure what output are you expecting, please provide expected output as well

Answer (score 0):

```js
let friends = [
  "oMaR",
  "mOhaMed",
  "tAwFIk",
  "aBdO",
  "OmrAn",
  "MoHanD",
  "AbdOlLaH",
];

let result=friends.map((a)=>a.split('').map(a=>a===a.toLowerCase()?a.toUpperCase():a.toLowerCase()).join(''));



console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice man good work